# A instrução INSERT conflitou com a restrição do FOREIGN KEY "FK_dbo.Contadores_dbo.Enderecos_EnderecoId"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ddd, automapper

Estou com dois problemas.
Eu tenho a entidade **Contador**, **Endereço** e **Cidade**.
Sempre que eu vou cadastrar um novo **contador**, eu tenho um `dropdowlist` que carrega as **cidades** para que eu possa escolher, o problema, é que ao invés de apenas selecionar a **cidade** para o **endereço** em questão, ele ta clonando a **cidade** no banco, ou seja, sempre que eu escolho a **cidade**, ele acaba salvando a mesma **cidade**, com um `Guid` diferente. o outro problema é que sempre que eu tendo salvar o contador, ele da a seguinte menssagem de erro:

> A instrução INSERT conflitou com a restrição do FOREIGN KEY
>   "FK_dbo.Contadores_dbo.Enderecos_EnderecoId". O conflito ocorreu no
>   banco de dados "Smc_DDD_data_guid", tabela "dbo.Enderecos", column
>   'EnderecoId'. A instrução foi finalizada.

Meu modelo Contador:

```
  public class Contador: Pessoa
    {
        public Contador()
        {
            ClienteId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public virtual EnderecoTerceiros Endereco { get; set; }
        public Guid EnderecoId { get; set; }
    }
```

Meu Modelo Enderecoterceiros:

```
public class EnderecoTerceiros
    {
        public EnderecoTerceiros()
        {
            EnderecoTerceirosId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        public Guid EnderecoTerceirosId { get; set; }
        public string Rua { get; set; }
        public string Bairro { get; set; }
        public string Cep { get; set; }
        public string Complemento { get; set; }
        public string Numero { get; set; }
        public Zona Zona { get; set; }
        public TipoDeEndereco TipoDeEndereco { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

        public virtual Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
        public Guid CidadeId { get; set; }

    }
```

Meu Modelo Cidades:

```
public class Cidade
    {
        public Cidade()
        {
            CidadeId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        public Guid CidadeId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public Estado Estado { get; set; }
        public Regioes Regioes { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    }
```

No meu controller está assim:

```
public ActionResult Create(ContadorViewModel contadorViewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewBag.CidadeId = new SelectList(_cidadeAppService.ObterTodos(), "CidadeId", "Nome");
                return View(contadorViewModel);
            }

            var cidade = _cidadeAppService.ObterPorId(contadorViewModel.Endereco.Cidade.CidadeId); // busca a cidade pois ela ta vinda com a propriedade "Nome" vazia, isso gera um erro de validação, pois como eu falei, ele ta salvando a cidade de novo
            contadorViewModel.Endereco.Cidade = cidade;
            contadorViewModel.ClienteId = Guid.NewGuid();
            contadorViewModel.Endereco.EnderecoTerceirosId = Guid.NewGuid();
            _enderecoAppService.Adicionar(contadorViewModel.Endereco);
            _contadorAppService.Adicionar(contadorViewModel);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");


        }
```

Contador Service:

```
 public class ContadorAppServico : AppServiceBase, IContadorAppService
    {
        private readonly IContadorRepositorio _repositorio;

        public ContadorAppServico()
        {
            _repositorio = new ContadorRepositorio();
        }
        public ContadorViewModel Adicionar(ContadorViewModel contadorViewModel)
        {
            var contador = Mapper.Map<Contador>(contadorViewModel);
            _repositorio.Adicionar(contador);
            return contadorViewModel;
        }
}
```

Interface De Serviço:

```
Public interface IContadorAppService:IDisposable
    {
        ContadorViewModel ObterPorId(Guid id);
        IEnumerable<ContadorViewModel> ObterTodos();
        ContadorViewModel ObterPorCnpj(string cnpj);
        ContadorViewModel Atualizar(ContadorViewModel contadorViewModel);
        ContadorViewModel Adicionar(ContadorViewModel contadorViewModel);
        void Remover(Guid id);
    }
```

Sercice do Endereço:

```
     public class EnderecoTerceirosAppService : AppServiceBase, IEnderecoTerceirosAppService
        {
            private readonly IEnderecoTerceirosRepositorio _repositorio;

            public EnderecoTerceirosAppService()
            {
                _repositorio = new EnderecoTerceirosRepositorio();
            }
            public EnderecoTerceirosViewModel Adicionar(EnderecoTerceirosViewModel enderecoViewModel)
            {
                var endereco = Mapper.Map<EnderecoTerceiros>(enderecoViewModel);
                _repositorio.Adicionar(endereco);
                return enderecoViewModel;
            }
}
```

Sinceramente falando, eu não sei pq ta salvando uma nova cidade. 
Minha Action Get Create Está assim:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.CidadeId = new SelectList(_cidadeAppService.ObterTodos(), "CidadeId", "Nome");
            return PartialView();
        }
```

E o DropDow está assim:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Endereco.Cidade.CidadeId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CidadeId, string.Empty, new { @class = "municipio caixa_texto", style = "" })
```

O nome da cidade está vindo Null para a conttroller, teóricamente isso não me causaria problema, já que eu só preciso do Guid, porém, como ta criando uma nova cidade, com a cidade que eu escolho, isso gera um erro da validação.

porém, depois que cria uma nova cidade, adiciona o endereço no banco, mas na hora de persistir o Contador, da o erro de conflito.

Comment: No seu método de ``create`` você está chamando ``_enderecoAppService.Adicionar(contadorViewModel.Endereco);``.

Por que está adicionado um novo endereço?

Comment: pq eu cadastro endereço e contador ao mesmo tempo, então eu mando pra view, contador e endereço.